# Why do we need main method when you have static blocks

Tags: java

This question was asked to someone I know.  What I could think of is that main method will be required to accept command line arguments as the method parameters.

Are there any other arguments in defense of `public static void main(String args[])` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- It makes it possible to *test* a main method
- It makes it possible to *invoke* a main method from other classes
- It makes it possible to invoke a main method multiple times, whereas type initialization only occurs once
- It makes it possible to create an instance of a class containing a main method without running the program.

The thought of type initialization for the "main" class blocking until the application has finished is abhorrent.

*Could* we cope with it? I dare say. But I suspect I would always end up writing:

```
public class EntryPoint
{
    static
    {
        // Workaround for entry points being static initializers
        String[] arguments = getArgumentsHoweverThatHappens();
        RealEntryPoint.execute(arguments);
    }
}
```

... and nothing else would ever touch `EntryPoint`.

Comment: Aren't these arguments generic to 'static block vs method' comparison? What would be particular to `main()` method?

Comment: @Nishan: Well, the fact that you *expect* a main method to quite possibly execute for a long time... whereas type initializers should generally be quick, not throw exceptions etc.

Comment: @Nishan: You talk about arguments "in defense of" a main method - are these points not enough?

Comment: It also defines the typical interface for a program run from the operating system in that it accepts an array of strings (command line arguments) and returns an integer (status code to indicate correct termination or type of error).

Answer (score 9):

Static initializers and the main method have different intents.  The main method's purpose is to be invoked if, and only if, the JVM is called with the containing class as the main class (or if it's called directly by code).  The purpose of static initialiers is to do class initialization.  Initializers are always run, but it's possible to have main methods that are not.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to above stated, the need for `main` (not the characteristics of static blocks) is that your application needs a starting point, thats is, when you execute your application, you pass the JVM dozens of classes and the JVM needs to know which method to invoke first in order to start and execute your application. You need to declare which point is the beginning of your application because the JVM can't guess it. (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 5):

*Static blocks* are meant to be run once the corresponding class is loaded. The `main()`, however, is the entry point to your program and as Jon said, it can be invoked multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly because of C.

It would be nice if any public static method can be the entry point, instead of just `main`